# Mocking Jobs in laravel 5.2 Unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, composer-php, mockery

I am pretty new to unit testing. I as asked to write unit test in my application. In my application we have controllers and services. I am trying to mock a job called from the controller like this.

```
$this->expectsJobs(App\Jobs\UploadResponseEmail::class);
```

This throws the following error

production.ERROR: Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_Illuminate_Bus_Dispatcher::dispatch(object(App\Jobs\UploadResponseEmail)). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

the Job has a constructor which expects an argument. I think that is causing error. How can I pass constructor argument here. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mockery to your composer.json file if you are using lumen. Laravel has it by default, so your question is about Lumen not Laravel

```
"mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
```

Even from Laravel 5.1 it was there:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/composer.json

Where as Lumen 5.2 it is missing:
https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/v5.2.1/composer.json